# Excel 'recently used list' not showing on start menu, but working within excel

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

In windows 7 when you pin Excel 2007 to the start menu, it usually has a small arrow which shows your recently opened documents. Mine only shows permanently pinned documents. It used to work until I tried Office 2010 and then uninstalled it. If I open Excel and click on the file menu, I can see all the recently opened documents so they are being recorded somewhere...

Any idea on how to restore it so I can view them on the start menu - Which I always used before?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://wintelteams.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/fix-windows-7-jump-lists-missing-or-does-not-display-recent-items-or-pinned-files/), the issue may happen because one of the Jump Lists’ recent items in automaticDestinations hidden system folder is corrupted.

Delete or clear Jumplist recent items in Windows 7 that is corrupted in AutomaticDestinations-hidden system folder is the likely solution.. To resolve and fix the issue, follow these steps:

1. Open Windows Explorer.
2. Type or copy and paste the following into the address bar: **%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations**
3. Identify files that are comparatively larger in size than the rest of the file, such as files that have file size of 1 MB or more. Delete the abnormal file. *Tip: If you does not want to retain the Jump Lists’ recent items history on all applications, just delete all the automaticDestinations-ms files in the folder.*
4. The recent items functionality on Jump Lists will be restored.

The recent items on the Jump Lists will be re-added as the program is been used. However, do note that the solution does not restore the previously pinned items. So user will have to pin new items again.

Comment: That would seems like the answer, certainly explains the problem exactly however it did not work for me.

Comment: Can you report what you have seen while following the article, and what are the contents of the AutomaticDestinations folder?

Comment: Comment: Maybe in Windows 7 you are supposed to pin Excel to the task-bar, rather than to the start menu.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Ekevoo: Another version might be found [in here](http://wintelteams.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/fix-windows-7-jump-lists-missing-or-does-not-display-recent-items-or-pinned-files/). The original can still be found on the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20100807185845/http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/07/04/fix-windows-7-jump-lists-missing-or-does-not-display-recent-items-or-pinned-files).

Comment: @harrymc Cool, thanks. Too bad that didn't fix it for me. :(

Answer (score 1):

Though it's been years since you asked this question, here is what to do in Excel 2010 (should also work for Excel 2007):

1. Right-click on the taskbar, that is, the bar at the bottom of your
   screen (where you see all the open applications minimized).
2. Click **Properties**.
3. Click the **Start Menu** tab.
4. Under **Privacy**, select both the below check boxes (where you
   currently see the second check box as "not selected"):

   - **Store and display recently opened programs in the Start menu**
   - **Store and display recently opened items in the Start menu and the taskbar**
5. Click **Apply** and then **OK**.

Once done, open any Excel file. The recent items will show the file(s) you just opened.